# How the best way to get the checkbox value in a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chb" value="True" checked="checked">
```

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(bool chb)
```

The error when I not check the checkbox:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'chb'
>   type that does not allow nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Search (System.String, System.String,
>   Boolean)' in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use helper Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.chb) or Html.EditorFor(x => x.chb) generated code will be

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chb" name="chb" value="True" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="chb" />
```

If checkbox isn't checked, only hidden field will be submited on chb model value will be set to false
Else if checkbox is checked form submit two fields but MVC set true to chb value

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you declare your Pesquisar as taking a nullable value?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(bool? chbNull) {
    var chb = chbNull ?? false;

    // rest of routine as existing
}
```

That may fix your issue since it sounds like the client is sending in a null value.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Checkbox("chb", ...)`

This will generate the checkbox input as well as a hidden input of the same name.  When the checkbox is unchecked the hidden value will be used to avoid the NullReferenceException.